# jQuery not displaying data

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, json

HTML CODE:

```
        <div class="col-sm-8" id="lists">
  <?php foreach($products as $p):?>
    <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="product-view row" style="border-bottom:1px solid #eee;margin-bottom:20px;padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;background:#f1f1f1">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <?php $j = 0;?>
        <?php foreach($p['checkbox'] as $checkbox):?>
          <?php if($j == 0):?>
            <div class="large-image"> 
                <img alt="#" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/uploads/<?php echo $checkbox['Image']?>" />
                <div class="image-title"><span class="icon-thumbs-up" style="font-size:18px;"><?php echo $p['Thumb']?></span></div> 
            </div>
          <?php endif;?>
          <?php $j++;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"> 
      <div class="product-label">
          <h4><?php echo $p["FullName"];?>, <?php echo $p["Area"];?></h4>
          <h5 style="font-size:14px"><span class="icon-calendar"></span>  <?php echo $p["SaleDate"];?></h5>
          <h5 style="font-size:14px"><span class="icon-clock"></span>
          <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($p['StartTime']); $i++):?>
              <?php echo $p['StartTime'][$i].'-'.$p['EndTime'][$i]?>
          <?php endfor;?>
          </h5>
          <div data-balloon-length="fit" data-balloon=" <?php echo $p["Address1"];?>" data-balloon-pos="up"  ><h5 style="font-size:14px;width: 100%;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;"><span class="icon-home"></span>  <?php echo $p["Address1"];?></h5></div>
          <div data-balloon-length="fit" data-balloon=" <?php echo $p["description"];?>" data-balloon-pos="up" ><h5 style="font-size:14px;width: 100%;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;"><span class="icon-file"></span>  <?php echo $p["description"];?></h5></div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <div class="product-label">
          <h4>CATEGORY</h4>
          <?php foreach($p['checkbox'] as $checkbox):?>
            <h5 style="font-size:14px"><?php echo $checkbox['Product']?></h5>
          <?php endforeach;?>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <?php endforeach;?>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/myad/filter",
                data:{checkbox:checked},
                success:function(data){
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        var list = '';
        var cates = '';
        for(var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++){
          list =+ '<div class="col-sm-12"><div class="product-view row" style="border-bottom:1px solid #eee;margin-bottom:20px;padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;background:#f1f1f1"><div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"> <div class="large-image"> <img alt="#" src="'+base_url+'/uploads/'+data[i]['cate'][0]['Image']+'"><div class="image-title"><span class="icon-thumbs-up" onclick="thumb('+data[i]['UniqueID']+',this)" style="font-size:24px;"></span></div></div></div><div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"> <div class="product-label"><h4>'+data[i]['FullName']+', '+data[i]['Area']+'</h4><h5 style="font-size:14px;width: 100%;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;"><span class="icon-calendar"></span>  '+data[i]['SaleDate']+'</h5><h5 style="font-size:14px;width: 100%;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;"><span class="icon-clock"></span>  ';
          var starttime = JSON.parse(data[i]['StartTime']);
          var endtime = JSON.parse(data[i]['EndTime']);
          var times='';
          for(var r = 0; r  < starttime.length; r++){
              times+=''+starttime[r]+'-'+endtime[r]+' ';
          }
          list+=times+'</h5><div data-balloon-length="fit" data-balloon="'+data[i]['Address1']+'" data-balloon-pos="up" ><h5 style="font-size:14px;width: 100%;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;"><span class="icon-home"></span>  '+data[i]['Address1']+'</h5></div><div data-balloon-length="fit" data-balloon="'+data[i]['description']+'" data-balloon-pos="up" ><h5 style="font-size:14px;width: 100%;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;"><span class="icon-file"></span>  '+data[i]['description']+'</h5></div></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div class="product-label"><h4>CATEGORY</h4>';
          for(var j = 0;j < data[i]['checkbox'].length; j++){
            cates+='<h5 style="font-size:14px">'+data[i]['cate'][j]['Product']+'</h5>';
          }
          list+=cates+'</div></div></div></div>';
        };
        $("#lists").html(list).hide().fadeIn();
              }
          });
```

Right now my PHP code is appearing php data. after a changing value of checkbox I want to display data on ID. but it not working. my checkbox code and ajax code is working correct. it displaying JSON data in console. but on changes of checkbox it not displaying data on ID how can I resolve it? and thanks in advance.

Comment: What does *"display data on ID"* mean? What triggers the ajax ? Problem is not very clear

Comment: @charlietfl on clicking on checkbox it calling ajax function

Comment: @charlietfl  I display content of list variable in lists

Comment: The whole problem is still not very clear. Suggest you update question making it more understandable and show the relevant code for the checkbox change also